# Why are members of the Cabinet allowed to resign without notice?

Tags: united-kingdom, cabinet

According to the Gov.UK website, one must give a week's notice if they wish to resign from their job and have been working for at least a month. ([Source](https://www.gov.uk/handing-in-your-notice/giving-notice))

Why does this one-week rule not apply to the Cabinet?

Comment: Would you want someone in the cabinet who doesn't want to be there?

Comment: No, but that would go with any other employee as well.

Comment: Untrue.  Large numbers of employees don't want to be there and only do so because they are paid.

Someone is said to resign when they hand in their notice.  Do you have evidence that cabinet ministers after handing in their notice routinely do not spend some time transitioning things to their successor?

Comment: @EricNolan If my perception is wrong, feel free to provide an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The notice period is set out by the [Employment Rights Act 1996](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1996/18/contents), and is specific to employees. Ministers are not working under a contract of employment, or, for that matter, any other sort of contract. That means they are not "employees" nor even "workers" under UK employment law. The most appropriate status is ["office holder"](https://www.gov.uk/employment-status/office-holder), for which the idea of "notice" (or for that matter "unfair dismissal") generally doesn't apply. The same is true for [all MPs](http://www.theipsa.org.uk/publications/freedom-of-information/2010-11/foi062/).